# Adding XY coordinates from a point feature class to a one to many related table in ArcGIS 10.0

Tags: arcgis-10.0, point, xy, relates

I have a point feature class with a one-to-many relate to a table. I would like to add the XY coordinates of each point in the feature class to the related table where the ID field matches. Of course, it's simple to get the XY coordinates for each point but it's adding them to the table where I'm getting stuck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000064000000) the table with XY information to the table without it.

From there, you can add permanent XY fields by [exporting the joined data.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003n00000037000000).

You can also do this by adding the XY fields first.  Then joining the tables, and calculating the XY values using the joined XY fields.  After you have done this, remove the join and you will have a XY fields for the table without spatial information.